# SwiftUI search list from JSON file

Tags: json, swift, search, swiftui

Currently my `SearchView` uses a simple filter on array `names` and I need it to make it search trough my JSON file. I have a JSON file with this structure:

```
struct UcmData: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let building: [Building]
}

// MARK: - Building
struct Building: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let title, subtitle, info, image: String
    let floor: [Floor]
}

// MARK: - Floor
struct Floor: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id, number: Int
    let title, subtitle, image: String
    let cabinet: [Cabinet]?
}

// MARK: - Cabinet
struct Cabinet: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let number: String
    let person: [Person]
}

// MARK: - Person
struct Person: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

SearchView:

```
struct SearchView: View {

    let names = ["306 B", "doc. Ing. Michal Čerňanský, PhD."]
    let ucmData = Bundle.main.decode(UcmData.self, from: "ucm_data.json")
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var showCancelButton: Bool = false


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    TextField("Zadajte text pre vyhľadávanie", text: $searchText, onEditingChanged: { isEditing in
                        self.showCancelButton = true
                    }, onCommit: {
                        print("onCommit")
                    }).foregroundColor(.primary)
                    Button(action: {
                        self.searchText = ""
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill").opacity(searchText == "" ? 0 : 1)
                    }
                }
                .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 6, bottom: 8, trailing: 6))
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                .cornerRadius(10.0)
                if showCancelButton  {
                    Button("Cancel") {
                            UIApplication.shared.endEditing(true)
                            self.searchText = ""
                            self.showCancelButton = false
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(Color(.systemBlue))
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .navigationBarHidden(showCancelButton)
            List {
                ForEach(self.names.filter{
                    self.searchText.isEmpty ? $0.localizedStandardContains("") :
                        $0.localizedStandardContains(self.searchText)
                }, id: \.self) { name in
                    Text(name)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Vyhľadávanie"))
            .resignKeyboardOnDragGesture()
        }
    }
}

extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing(_ force: Bool) {
        self.windows
            .filter{$0.isKeyWindow}
            .first?
            .endEditing(force)
    }
}

struct ResignKeyboardOnDragGesture: ViewModifier {
    var gesture = DragGesture().onChanged{_ in
        UIApplication.shared.endEditing(true)
    }
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.gesture(gesture)
    }
}

extension View {
    func resignKeyboardOnDragGesture() -> some View {
        return modifier(ResignKeyboardOnDragGesture())
    }
}

struct SearchView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
           SearchView()
              .environment(\.colorScheme, .light)

           SearchView()
              .environment(\.colorScheme, .dark)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make match the `searchText` with `Cabinet.number` or `Person.name` and list matching items with their path in JSON file e.g. "building.title > floor.title > cabinet.number" or for person "building.title > floor.title > cabinet.number > person.name"? Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure but I am assuming the search field can have either a person's name or a cabinet number based on which you want to filter your dataset and show a list in the fashion:

> building.title > floor.title > cabinet.number
>
> or
>
> building.title > floor.title > cabinet.number > person.name

Maybe something along these lines might help:

```
struct ContentView: View {
  let data: UcmData
  @State var searchString = ""

  var found: [String] {
    var result = [String]()
    data.building.forEach { (building) in //go through every building
      building.floor.forEach { (floor) in //go through every floor
        floor.cabinet?.forEach { (cabinet) in //go through every cabinet
          var cabinetFound: String {
            return "\(building.title) > \(floor.title) > \(cabinet.number)"
          }

          if cabinet.number == searchString { //check with cabinet [!]
            result.append(cabinetFound) //add search result
          } else {
            cabinet.person.forEach { (person) in //go through every person
              if person.name == searchString { //check with person [!]
                let personFound = cabinetFound + " > \(person.name)"
                result.append(personFound) //add search result
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result
  }

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      TextField("search string", text: $searchString) //search field
      List(found, id: \.self) { (current) in //List of search results
        Text(current)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

<sup>*This example is just a sub-set of your view to showcase only the search functionality. Integrate it if it makes sense.</sup>

1. `found` is an `Array` of `String` that will be computed when requested
2. When search field updates, `searchString` updates and re-renders the body which will refresh the `List` with elements in `found`

---

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank You very much! I couldn't figure out how to compose the `var found` you created, all I needed was to implement your code and substitute `if cabinet.number == searchString` and also condition for `person.name` with `if cabinet.number.localizedStandardContains(searchString)` to make it more "fulltext search" like, because I wanted the search to list all possible matches, not just the exact one correctly typed when searching. Then it worked like a charm, thank You once again!